# How to create an XML <ABC Name="XYZ" Place="DEF" /> in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Iam trying to create an XML in a particular format

Format Needed

```
<ROWDATA> <ROW NAME="ABC" PLACE="DEF"/> </ROWDATA>
```

Currently the format is getting as

```
<ROWDATA>

<ROW>NAME="ABC" PLACE="DEF" </ROW> </ROWDATA>
```

**Code**

```
XmlWriterSettings wSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
wSettings.Indent = true;
wSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
wSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, wSettings);
xw.WriteStartElement("ROWDATA");

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{

   xw.WriteStartElement("ROW");
   xw.WriteString("NAME=" + "''" + dts1.Rows[i]["NAME"].ToString() + "''");
   xw.WriteString("PLACE=" + "''" + dts1.Rows[i]["PLACE"].ToString() + "''");
   xw.WriteEndElement();
}
```

What change i have to do for getting output in the below format

```
<ROWDATA>
<ROW NAME="ABC" PLACE="DEF"/>
</ROWDATA>
```

Comment: Just curious why this is down-voted, seems like a reasonable question with an attempt at a solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `XmlWriter`? LINQ to XML is much easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the [`WriteAttributeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("NAME", dts1.Rows[i]["NAME"].ToString()); 
writer.WriteAttributeString("PLACE", dts1.Rows[i]["PLACE"].ToString());
```

Comment: To the down-voter: I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: You are not encouraging good coding practices with such code... see @John Saunders answer for a better answer.

Comment: That's a very subjective statement. I have never heard that using Xmlwriter is a bad practice. My task was to point out the error in OPs code, not to rewrite his code.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use LINQ to XML, you could do something like this:

```
var doc = new XElement("ROWDATA",
                        new XElement("ROW",
                                     new XAttribute("NAME", "ABC"),
                                     new XAttribute("PLACE", "DEF")));
```